# Different size blocks best allocation to fixed size buckets

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an interesting (or maybe its plain simple) problem to solve.
There are different size blocks (say any real numbers like 0.5 or 50) to allocate among buckets. Bucket size is always 64.

The problem to solve is to allocate the blocks in such a way that least amount of space in buckets is wasted.

Going for naive solution one can just iterate over buckets and push nth element into first bucket that the block can fit into. If there are no buckets that can fit the element - new bucket is created.

Is there any better way to do that or is the naive solution also an optimal solution?

Comment: [Check bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: thanks, thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mathematically complex question called the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

You probably won't find an easy way to implement the [optimal soloution](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/IJCAI/IJCAI13/paper/view/6851/6656).  [This](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/bpack/bpack.htm) page mentions one solution, to always put the block in the fullest bucket that can fit it.

I think analyzing the entire dataset beforehand is the key to an optimal solution, but it doesn't seem like it will be easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the buckets sorted by available space (e.g. from the max space available till the least space available. Your algorithm would be:

1. Initially the list is empty.
2. Create the first block for the new coming block.
3. The next one one is coming. Check if it fits into the first bucket. If doesn't, create a new one and check for available. If the new one has more available space than the first one, place it in front of the list, otherwise append to the end.
4. Essentially the problem narrows down to performing a binary search to find which of the buckets will fit the new element and finding a new place for the element you've updated at the current step.

Comment: This does not always find the optimal solution.